# Problem with the length of path in GCC

Tags: java, windows, gcc

I had a problem with the limitation of paths
Here for example I run this command... :

> String[] cmd = new String[]
>   {"command.com","/C",
>                                "Resource\\gcc.exe",
>                                 "-E",
>                                 in_path,
>                                 ">",
>                                 "out_path"};

in_path : the path where is contain the directory of file cpp
out_path: output file after processing the first bearing the same name as input and thus fichier.cpp

for exemple: 
          in_path=  d:/directorycpp/file1.cpp 
          out_path= file1.cpp

Well there are two cases that don't function in tests
If the path is set when the cpp file for the test is too long
If the path is short and that the file name contains more than 8caractère then it goes not so.
I read that gcc has limited character, but when I run
my command in command prompt it passes
So why does not work in my case
Should I add an option or another??

Answer (score 2):

Change `"Resource\gcc.exe"` to `"Resource\\gcc.exe"`.

Comment: I work in XP windows, and you can not do like this
the problem is in the limitation of paths  cause with the short path it work very well

Comment: Regardless of any perceived problem with path lengths, you still need to fix the escaping of backslash characters in C/C++ string literals.

Comment: OK sorry I haven't give you the right syntaxe
this is what I have do
String[] Commande = new String[] {"command.com","/C",                           "Resource\\gcc.exe",
                                  "-E",                     "-B","Resource",
                                  in_path,
                                  ">",
                                  "test\\"+out_path};
Here where the path is short the program work very wel
And I do this before the commande 
in_path =in_path.replace("\\", "/");
I work in JAVA

Comment: OK - I have now slightly edited and re-tagged your post to reflect what you're actually trying to do. It sounds like a Windows issue but I don't know anything about Windows, sorry.